# Use Case Diagram - Is this Correct?

Tags: dependencies, uml, use-case

I've recently been trying to get my head around the include and extend dependencies that are used in use case diagrams.
I thought I had fully understood the difference between them until I came across this sample model as an exam question solution.

[image: Use case diagram example]

I am focusing mainly on the use cases towards the top of the diagram. Now surely if a customer wants to place an order for an item, it is essential for the customers credit to be verified, it isn't something that should be optional... Therefore the 'place order for goods' use case should be dependent on the 'verify credit' use case by using the include dependency.

So that being said, my interpretation of the dependency is shown in the diagram below.

[image: Correct? Use case diagram example]

Could someone please give me their opinion on what should be the correct way of representing this dependency? (include or extend??)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not correct. The meaning of include/extend is about optionality of use cases (whether you implement them at all/sooner/later) and not about whether one use case "calls" another one. A use case itself must be complete in the sense that it returns additional value to its actor. Don't fall in the pit to make functional decomposition with use cases. This is wrong and it turns your use case diagram into a spider's web. Remove all include/extend and connect `Produce Quotation` directly to its actor.

You might want to use roles and generalization. E.g. you could generalize from `Spec. Team` to `Customer` to tell that they can act as customer and link a constraint that it's only meaningful for a certain use case (`Place Order for...`).

My condolence for using Rational - ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your response. So in regards to the 'Verify credit' use case, 'place order for goods' and 'place order for manufactured goods'... Your saying the second diagram is correct, having used the include dependency as opposed to the extend dependency in the model answer?

Comment: I'm still finding it difficult to understand which of the two diagrams I've provided is more correct. The first one using the extend dependency is a model answer so it should be correct? I however believe that include would be more correct in this scenario. Considering only include and extend which one would you consider more correct? Sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: Okay thanks again for taking the time to answer. I am going to re-read and dissect your answer and discuss it with my lecturer. He produced the first diagram as a model answer so he is wrong which is worrying considering this was a model answer in a mark scheme for an official exam :/.

Comment: You might point him to this discussion: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/143183-6000866789691580416 It took me almost 10 years before understanding the use of i/e and I always avoided them as suggested by Bittner/Spence and others (which was a good advice).